# Как сделать чтобы на html странице картинка и текст перетаскивались вместе?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Нужно чтобы на html странице картинка и текст перетаскивались вместе, одним блоком. Подскажите как это можно сделать?

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
  function startDrag(e) {
    var e = e || window.event;
    e.dataTransfer.setData('text', e.target.id);
    e.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = 'move';

    return true;
  }

  function endDrag(e) {
    var e = e || window.event;
    e.dataTransfer.clearData('text');

    return true;
  }

  function drop(e) {
    var e = e || window.event;
    e.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(e.dataTransfer.getData('Ball')));

    e.stopPropagation ? e.stopPropagation() : e.cancelBubble = true;
    return false;
  }
</script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="conteiner h7-position">
    <div align="center" class=" col-lg-4 ">
      <img alt="" class="img-h7" src="img/img_left3.png">
      <p class="h7-text1-position">CREATIVE MINDS</p>
      <img src="img/divider.png" alt="img3" class="devider-h7">
      <p class="h7-text2-position text-grey teame-text-format">orem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc ultricies nulla non metus pulvinar imperdiet. Praesent non adipiscing libero.</p>
    </div>
    <div align="center" class=" col-lg-4">
      <img src="img/img-center3.png" alt="imgC3" class="img-h7">
      <p class="h7-text1-position">THINK ALIKE</p>
      <img src="img/divider.png" alt="img3" class="devider-h7">
      <p class="h7-text2-position text-grey teame-text-format">orem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc ultricies nulla non metus pulvinar imperdiet. Praesent non adipiscing libero.</p>
    </div>
    <div align="center" class=" col-lg-4 ">
      <img src="img/img_right3.png" alt="imgR3" class="img-h7">
      <p class="h7-text1-position">PIXEL PERFECTION</p>
      <img src="img/divider.png" alt="img3" class="devider-h7">
      <p class="h7-text2-position text-grey teame-text-format">orem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc ultricies nulla non metus pulvinar imperdiet. Praesent non adipiscing libero.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: что вы понимаете под "перетаскивались"? Обернуть их одним DIV'om например

Comment: Дмитрий,под перетаскивать понимается возможность переносить объекты с страницы например в ворд. Обернуть в одним div-ом уже пробовал. не помогает.

Comment: переносить объекты в word??? я думал туда копипастят? или вы это по другому делаете? опишите процедуру.

Comment: Опишите, пожалуйста, более подробно контекст вашей проблемы. Желательно привести ваше решение, которое у вас не работает.

Comment: vp_arth ,[ссылка](https://yadi.sk/i/8Jpeq3CV3E4Nt9) картинка и текст перетаскиваются отдельно друг от друга а должны вместе.

Comment: @Дмитрий первый раз вижу такой способ показать код, жесть) Вы можете его закинуть либо в вопрос, либо на сервисы codepen/jsfiddle. И приведите код того, что вы хотите тащить - Обычный текст с картинкой

Comment: Тащить нужно картинку и находящийся под ней текст. Никаких форм никаких списков.Функция перетаскивания элементов реализована. необходимо объединить текст и картинку.